# Delete element using javascript

Tags: javascript, xhtml

I have a textbox. On focus I call a javascript function in which I create a new element with this way:

```
var label = document.createElement("label");
label.innerHTML = "*For a more secure password use letters and digits";
document.getElementById('picturediv').appendChild(label);
```

But `onblur` I call another function and then I want to remove this element. I've tried with the remove but it is not working. I am not sure if the remove is suitable for that.

Comment: removeChild is the function you need.

Comment: these are not the droids you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove it this way:

```
function removeLabel() {
    document.getElementById('picturediv').removeChild(document.getElementById('picturediv').getElementsByTagName('label')[document.getElementById('picturediv').getElementsByTagName('label').length - 1]);
}
```

edit:

The function with comments:

```
function removeLabel() {
    var parentNode = document.getElementById('picturediv'); // The parentNode of the label element

    var tagsWithLabel = parentNode.getElementsByTagName('label'); // All elements with tag name label

    var length = tagsWithLabel.length; // The length of the node array

    parentNode.removeChild(tagsWithLabel[length - 1]); // Deleting the last element with tage name label from parentNode.
}
```

edit because of comment:

```
function removeLabel(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).removeChild(document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName('label')[document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName('label').length - 1]);
}
```

to delete label 1: `removeLabel('picturediv');` to delete label 2: `removeLabel('picturediv2');`

Comment: Hi again! I want to give a different name to the label. I create the label but i can't delete. Probably I am doing something wrong but I can't figure out whta! I am using this line. Is this ok? document.getElementById('picturediv2').removeChild(document.getElementById('picturediv2').getElementsByTagName('label2')[document.getElementById('picturediv2').getElementsByTagName('label2').length - 1]);

Comment: I create the new element with these lines:     var label2 = document.createElement("label");
    label2.innerHTML = "Your password should be 6 to 20 characters long.";
    document.getElementById('picturediv2').appendChild(label2);

Comment: if I change this createElement("label") to this createElement("label2") it works fine... but it does not make sense for me. Also I tried to do the same for an image and it works only if i name everything "img". Here is the code var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute('alt', 'attention');
    img.setAttribute('width', '20px');
    img.setAttribute('src', 'images/attention!.png');
    document.getElementById('picturediv2').appendChild(img);

Comment: @anna i edited my answer again. Please try the last code (removeLabel(id)).

Comment: Unfortunatelly I can't upvote for you more than once. Thank you sooooo much for your help. Maybe I will send you again, if i have other problems!!! Thank you once again!!!